# how to insert tabs instead of spaces when creating xml files in python

Tags: python, xml, tabs, elementtree, spaces

I m using

[Creating a simple XML file using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605680/creating-a-simple-xml-file-using-python)

and

[inserting newlines in xml file generated via xml.etree.ElementTree in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095434/inserting-newlines-in-xml-file-generated-via-xml-etree-elementtree-in-python)

but my xml subelement has 2 spaces from left, instead of a tab, how do I switch to a tab for a subelement and not 2 spaces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `indent` argument of [`toprettyxml()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.minidom.html#xml.dom.minidom.Node.toprettyxml) to `\t`:

```
from xml.dom import minidom
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

root = ET.Element("root")

doc = ET.SubElement(root, "doc")

field1 = ET.SubElement(doc, "field1")
field1.set("name", "blah")
field1.text = "some value1"

field2 = ET.SubElement(doc, "field2")
field2.set("name", "asdfasd")
field2.text = "some vlaue2"

dom = minidom.parseString(ET.tostring(root))
print dom.toprettyxml(indent='\t')
```

prints:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<root>
    <doc>
        <field1 name="blah">some value1</field1>
        <field2 name="asdfasd">some vlaue2</field2>
    </doc>
</root>
```

Comment: is there some way to not add the <?xml version="1.0" ?>
line?

Comment: @user494461 it is minidom inserting it, see this relevant thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933262/how-to-write-an-xml-file-without-header-in-python

Comment: And how do you save it like that?